# Replacing keyword in string that is HTML page using Java

Tags: java, html, string, replace

I have following string:

```
<html>
<head><meta>...</meta><head>
<body>
   <div id="foo">
     Text I want to search & replace occurrences
     of keywords such as Foo or foo while ignoring case
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
<html>
<head><meta>...</meta><head>
<body>
   <div id="foo">
     Text I want to search & replace occurrences
     of keywords such as <b>Foo</b> or <b>foo</b> while ignoring case
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So pretty much I'd like to search for and replace `foo` with `<b>foo</b>` or `<b>Foo</b>`. It is important to retain the case of the string that is being replace but match it with keyword `foo` while ignoring the case of the matches.

Another important thing is that the replacement ignores all html tags and their content. Notice that `<div id="foo">` stays like it is.

I drafted this but didn't test it yet

```
 text = text.replace("(?i)"+keyword+"(?!([^<]+)?>)", "<b>"+keyword+"</b>");
```

The problem with the above is that it doesn't remember the case of word that is being replaced and just puts in the keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + keyword + ")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "<b>$1</b>")
```

Comment: Did you vote down on my answer just because I answered first?

Comment: A backreference to the entire match is indicated as $0. If there are capturing parentheses, you can reference specifics groups as $1, $2, etc.

Comment: @adrianboimvaser: No ! I didn't ! I was actually about to delete mine when I saw yours, but then I realized you wrote $0... Did you do that with my answer ? :)

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu: I'm sorry, I saw my first vote vanish. Of course not!

Comment: @adrianboimvaser: I know, I was just kidding. Maybe my "answer" should've been only a comment to yours... @Mat Banik: you should accept the first answer with but with the small fix that I posted: $1 instead of $0 :)

Comment: Thanks a tonn for sharing..You saved my time ..keep coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [capturing group](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html), and, by the way, use `replaceAll`

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)("+keyword+")(?!([^<]+)?>)", "<b>$0</b>");
```

Comment: replaceAll() takes a regular expression, while replace() just takes a literal sequence

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this, i.e. word boundary should be set:

```
text.replaceAll("(?i)(\\b" + keyword + "\\b)(?!([^<]+)?>)", "<b>$1</b>")
```